# How Asset Publisher show the contents?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6.2

I'm developing a custom portlet like the Asset Publisher OOB Liferay but my portlet have to show all types of Contents (Published, expired, save as draft etc etc).

My problem is that I'm not be able to open my jsp with the Content in a new page like Asset Publisher does, because naturally i open the content in the same space where the portlet is deployed.

https://domain/-/ContentTitle.

But if i try to go this type of URL trouhgt my porlet, i receive the error "Resource not found"

Could anyone help me to replicate this funcionality of the Asset Publisher of Liferay?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this article and add information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information Olaf, i didn't noticed this point of view. I will post in SO then.
Regarding my trouble, any idea of how i can achieve it?

Comment: I've seen how the assetPublisher do the functionality i want.
It uses the following two sentences:
<#assign viewURL = AssetPublisherHelper.getAssetViewURL(renderRequest, renderResponse, entry) /><#assign viewURL = assetRenderer.getURLViewInContext(renderRequest, renderResponse, viewURL) />

How can I obtain this objects in JAVA?